# Get a span element without the leading space IF it is being displayed as the first element on a line

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a div that wraps a number of spans each with a single word in them.  Most of these spans have a leading space, but if they wrap to another line, the space doesn't show.

IF the span is currently displaying a word/element that is the first word of a line, I would like to get that element without the space.  However, if the element is displaying the space I want to get the element with the leading space.

In this example, the words 'The', 'Example' and 'You' all start on a new line and the leading space doesn't show.

One thought I had was to do a regex for a new line indicator and if there is one, to remove the leading space, but not sure that is the ideal way to handle it.

My ultimate goal is to get the exact position and size of the span and the text within it.  I am finding, however, that when I do this, I am getting the leading spaces even when they aren't being shown.  If I could ONLY get the text, size and position and completely leave all of the spaces out of the question, I am fine with that too.

Here is an image showing that the word "example" and "you" both are showing without an initial space due to the wrapping.

[image]

So, after I run my .each function on the div in question I would want the following data:

```
This
 is
 an
example
 for
you
 to
 examine
```

```js
jQuery('.test').each(function(index, value) {


var theword = jQuery(this).text();

console.log("The Word "+theword);


});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:100px" class="test">
<span>This</span>
<span> is</span>
<span> an</span>
<span> example</span>
<span> for</span> 
<span> you</span>
<span> to</span>
<span> examine</span>
</div>
```

My ultimate goal is to accurately get size and positioning data of each span word.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure sure what exactly you're trying to achieve but this loops through the spans and shows if it has a space and returns true or false and also the position in the loop.

Is this what you need or do you want the span before or after it? Not quite clear? Also get the size of what? Sorry but your question is not quite clear.

```js
    var count = 0;

function hasWhiteSpace(s) {
  return (/\s/).test(s);
}

var reWhiteSpace = new RegExp("\\s+");
$(".test span").each(function(){
var test = $(this).text();
var result = (hasWhiteSpace(test));
count++;

if (result === true) {
console.log(test + ', HAS a space at position : ' + count);
} else {
console.log(test + ', has NO space at position : ' + count);
}

if (count === 1) {
alert ('*'+ test + '*' + ' is the first word with a without a space in the spans');
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
<div style="width:100px" class="test">
<span class=test">This</span>
<span class=test"> is</span>
<span class=test"> an</span>
<span class=test"> example</span>
<span class=test"> for</span> 
<span class=test"> you</span>
<span class=test"> to</span>
<span class=test"> examine</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @JulesUK and sorry for the confusion.  I edited the original question a bit.  Ultimately, I just want to get the exact size, position and text in the span as it is seen on the screen.  I really don't need the spaces at all, as long as I can get that data accurately.  If I access and parse the data either via .html or .txt the space is being included even though it isn't being shown on the screen, so that is the problem.

Comment: Check this now? Still not quite sure what you mean though? I have updated answer

Comment: Testing this and will report back.  Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a &nbsp; to where the space is?

Comment: Actually, no it wont work. I added an image in my original question to clarify and some more info. I only want to remove the space from the text IF it is displaying as the first word in the line. You can see the word "Example" and "You" both have leading spaces in the html, but those spaces don't show because they are on new lines due to the wrapping.

Comment: Sorry totally misunderstood what you wanted!!! Its clear now, will look into it now

Comment: Sorry mate got me stumped! I can count the lines of text and what i been trying to do it save the words in each line into array and compare to the first one. I just cant seen to do it, sorry!

Comment: No worries!  Thanks for trying, I will keep going at it.